# Accidental deletion on Laravel Migration gives me migration not found

Tags: laravel

I accidentally deleted a migration file via my IDE manually earlier, after creating it and running `php artisan migrate`. now when im trying to run `php artisan migrate:rollbac`k, i get `Migration not found: 2020_03_02_074557_add_dispute_into_company_order` . How can i get my migration back?

Comment: if you have git repo then you recover it from there

Comment: @Sehdev unfortunately, it was on my local, i didnt push it up. :/

Comment: is it current session of IDE or you have closed the IDE and opened again ? If it is current session, you can click on any files on the sidebar and click on Undo. It may get back your deleted file.

Comment: cant undo, but once i created the migration again, it worked just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rollback did not execute the task due to missing migration you may have a chance to recover your sql schema from database itself. From that part you can manually create a new migration.

Alternatively you can do as SKR suggested: try clicking 'undo' in your IDE.

Comment: so what i did was, i just created the migration again, and it works fine somehow...

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try:
composer dump-autoload
It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project
```